# Envio de JSON para web-service via Http

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma duvida que creio ser simples de resolver, tenho um Web service que alimenta meu App, eu consigo fazer a requisição dessas informações mas não consigo enviar informações, o mais próximo que cheguei até o momento foi:

```
JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonParams.put("teste", 1);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Log.d("JSON",jsonParams.getString("teste"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto);
    //url aponta para um servidor local http://192.160.0.xxx:8080/web_server_sdc/
    String url =Comunicacao.getInstance().getIp()+"finalizar.php";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest joReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonParams,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("Resposta", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Resposta", error.getMessage());

                }
            });
```

Quando executo esse trecho de código recebo o seguinte erro:

```
D/Resposta:org.json.JSONException:Value < br of type java.lang.String 
  cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

No web service tem o seguinte código:

```
echo '{"erro":"erro"}';
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Nem que seja um link para algum tutorial

Comment: Voce ja tentou debugar a linha que esta dando erro e ver qual valor ela esta retornando? Nesse arquivo voce esta apenas fazendo requisição no servidor. Caso esteja com dificuldades pra usar o Volley, tente usar o Retrofit, tem muito conteudo dele em portugues no youtube.

Comment: Acabei por desistir de fazer uma requisição JSON e fiz uma requisição utilizando uma String json, ao menos deu certo...